# Integrating Azure Bot with Azure Speech Services

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, microsoft-speech-api, azure-speech

Is there a possible way to integrate the speech services with bot? So i would like to know what is the process that goes in the integration of Speech Services with Bot?

How is it possible to do the integration with bot through the key that is obtained from the Azure Speech Service created?
And how to check whether the created Speech Services is working? 
Is there any common portal for the Speech Services to be tested like the portal for custom speech(https://westus.cris.ai/Home/CustomSpeech)?

And What are the different ways for integrating?

Comment: Your question is too large to get a good reply, but just to let you know: the Webchat for Bot Framework, provided by Microsoft, has a built-in capability to use Speech Services, see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/#enabling-speech-capabilities . The main problem for other channels is the fact that this speech treatment is done on the channel side

Comment: Is there any portal where i can test my created speech services?

Comment: You can test speech services that are attached to a bot the same way you would normally test the bot: either through the 'test in web chat' on the azure portal, or through the bot emulator locally.

Comment: thanks JJ_Wailes, but is there any way to test speech services alone in a seperate portal?

Comment: You mean test the speech services outside using the bot framework?

Comment: yeah, is there a way to test the text to speech in any portal?

Answer (score 0):

To test the speech service whether works, you can use the code sample provided by Microsoft without write addition code. Refer to the [Next steps section of Text to Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/text-to-speech)

Or you can make the REST API using POST man according the documentation.

And to [integrate the Speech Service with Bot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/), you can refer the figure below:
[image]